# Conditional search result statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom search.php and would like to know how to return a different statement based on the number of search results. I would like a different statement for each of three scenarios:

1. No results are returned
2. One result is returned
3. More than one result is returned

So in the first example the page will return No results where returned. In the second: Your search for X returned one result. And in the third: Your search for X returned Y results.

OK, hope that explains what I am trying to do. So here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;
?>
Your search for <span class="style"><?php echo get_search_query(); ?></span> returned <span class="style"><?php echo $total_results; ?></span> results.
```

So I am able to print out the third option, are there some conditionals I can use with this or any other code to create the different statements I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that `$total_results` is your count;

```
if($total_results==1){
    echo 'message one';
    ?> or jump out of PHP and back in <?PHP
}elseif($total_results>1){
    echo 'message multiple';
}else{
    echo 'no results (or error if you did not trap seperately)';
}
```

am I missing something?  could also look at `switch()` construct as well.

Comment: Do you mean `switch` instead of `case()`?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, a simple If/Else block should handle it:

```
if($total_results>1)
    echo 'more than one';
elseif($total_results==1)
    echo '1';
else
    echo '0';
```